# How to pass selected index id to another TableViewControl and Compare using Parse in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

For Example:=  According to Perticular State all City display in another view Controller's TableView.

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *identifier = @"cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        }
    PFObject *tempobj=[list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text=[tempobj objectForKey:@"stateName"];

    return cell;
}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"Tapped");

    CityController *obj=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CityController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Notify, it will keep the controllers from needing to know about each other.